# Как переписать класс без операторов "?:" и "=>"?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Как переписать класс, приведенный ниже, без операторов "?:" и "=>" и других "нововведений", чтобы код работал под .Net Framework 4.0 в VS2010?

```
    class XmlAttributeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
          => value is IEnumerable<XmlNode> values
            ? values.OfType<XmlAttribute>().Select(xa => xa.Value)
            : value;

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
          => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: `=>...` заменить на `{ return .... }`, `is ...` заменить на `.GetType() == typeof(...)`, `... ? ... : ...` на `if (..) return ... else return ...`

Comment: [https://psv4.userapi.com/c505536/u102145534/docs/d11/1cfd3a619dc1/1.jpg?extra=MCwWWmztSjd840PdmxEUDfps1tjYFDgiu5xLUlZEL4Fx_TbyFUN-0DudS2WSnMi-jYRvWYDkVm3vkbOIasIi38HDiyagB4_XarioyGuxbv1IDXXNyBZ5gydviD5qUx1U8UJlMsUjw-U6AmXowJAaLJ2JAQ]

Comment: ну вот дальше так и переписывайте. причем ? : можно оставлять. заменяйте => на фигурные скобки с ретурном

Comment: Framework 4.0... (перекрестился и пошел дальше)

Comment: @aepot - многие продукты jetbrains (или даже все), например, Resharper, пишутся на .net fw (чтобы побольше аудиторию охватить). Может у автора та же ситуация.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov DNF != DNF 4.0, в 4.7.2 например еще жить можно.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Разве тернарных операторов не было в .NET FW 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

```cs
class XmlAttributeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       if (value is IEnumerable<XmlNode>)
       {
           IEnumerable<XmlNode> values = (IEnumerable<XmlNode>)value;
           return values.OfType<XmlAttribute>().Select(xa => xa.Value);
       }
       else
           return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код работает у меня, но немного скорректированный:
[https://sun9-8.userapi.com/impg/oWljr58yIzoZ8S-FKYXRlq4dfZrfMacHdLoYkQ/znFiNijyNeE.jpg?size=1609x688&quality=96&sign=42a625090bbc5f91b977c99ed78832a1&type=album]